# Why is my selected value not updated when copied from a controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu

I have a `<select>` that is controlled using both `ng-model` and `ng-options`:

```
 <select ng-model="user.option"
         ng-options="value.label for (key, value) in data.options">
   <option value="">Select value</option>
 </select>
```

The options are grouped in an object:

```
$scope.data.options = {
    one: { label: 'one' },
    two: { label: 'two' }
};
```

At some point, I want to change the selected option from the controller. This works:

```
$scope.user.option = $scope.data.options['two'];
```

However, in my context, I maintain a variable `master`, and use it to set `$scope.user`:

```
$scope.master.option = $scope.data.options['two'];
$scope.user = angular.copy ($scope.master);
```

This does not work: my `<select>` still shows `Select value`. But other elements properly reflect the change.

What am I doing wrong?

I created a fiddle [there](http://jsfiddle.net/9ctbcwtv/).

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: You basically break the link between the `user` in your controller and the one in your `<select>`. Use `angular.extend($scope.user, $scope.master)` instead.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Noted. No human touch... I could have removed it myself though.

Comment: Sorry, I don't usually add the comment for users with >100 rep. I didn't notice this time.

Comment: @Blackhole This works indeed, thanks. I guess I have to better study how Angular binds data... But why does the other element did reflect the change anyway?

Comment: `$scope.user` has changed correctly. The problem is that the object `{ label: 'two' }` stored in `$scope.data.options` isn't the same that the one stored in `$scope.user` after the copy. Since `ngOptions` check for equality by reference, it doesn't find the appropriate object and behaves as if no value is selected.

Comment: @Blackhole The appropriate solution was to use `angular.extend()` as suggested by your comment; would you mind making it an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I'll do it as soon as possible. Don't hesitate to remind it to me if that isn't done by the end of the week!

Answer (score 0):

```
//Add  track by in ng-options ..check below code
<div ng-app="my-app">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
     <select ng-model="user.option"
             ng-options="value.label for (key, value) in data.options track by value.label">
       <option value="">Select value</option>
     </select>
     <p>Selected: {{user.option.label}}
  </div>
</div>
```